# NetworkStream Read() takes 5 seconds

Tags: c#, networkstream

I've an implementation of a `NetworkStream` to read and send data. Sometimes my `Read()` command takes about 5 seconds. The amount of data is small, < 100 bytes.
It is like it's trying to read something when there's no data. No data is received after these 5 seconds (receivedLength=0).
Is there any built in timeout in the read command? I'm not using `NetworkStream.ReceiveTimeout` since it'll close the connection.

The problem only seems to appear on some computers.

```
while (ReceiveStream.DataAvailable)
{
    // Receive
    lock (MessageBuffer)
    {
        int remainingLength = MessageBuffer.Length - MessageBufferUsedLength;

        try
        {
            int receivedLength = ReceiveStream.Read(MessageBuffer, MessageBufferUsedLength, remainingLength);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
}
...
```

Comment: Although this doesn't solve your problem, you might be able to run the code asynchronously. (I assume this 5 seconds is a long time since it's blocking your UI, and running it asynchronously won't block your UI.)

Comment: I suggest you use something like Wireshark to see when the packets are actually being transmitted. Bear in mind that `Stream.Read` will block until it receives *something* - if the other end of the connection is waiting before sending the data (e.g. to see if there's more that can be included in the packet) that could explain it.

Comment: I've used Wireshark, it says that data is coming. How can dataAvailable=true when there's no actual data?

Comment: Given the practically non-existent code example, it could be anything causing the delay. Maybe the `lock` is blocked by some other thread. Maybe the internal network buffer got flushed. Maybe the connection was reset. Frankly, you should not need the `lock` (that buffer has no business being accessed by any other thread until the operation is done), and you definitely shouldn't be swallowing exceptions like that. If the read completes with `0` bytes as the result, then the connection was closed by the other end. So maybe the other end just waits 5 seconds and then closes the connection.